# Developer tool can't find element with Xpath but Xpath helper extension can

Tags: selenium, xpath, developer-tools, katalon-studio

[image: Xpath helper vs Developer tool (1 result vs 0 results)]

Why is isn't developer tools able to find it ? I'm sure the xpath is correct since it also works in my code.

Comment: Elements panel is right, that's the wrong @class attribute.

Comment: Damn i see, stupid mistake..